# connect median values in a plot by a line

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = iris) + 
  stat_summary(mapping = aes(Species, Sepal.Length),
               fun.min = min,
               fun.max = max,
               fun = median)
```

I would like to connect the median values with a line. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add another `stat_summary()` with a line/path geom. You just need to suspend the grouping, since it interprets the x-axis as grouping.

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = iris, mapping = aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.min = min,
               fun.max = max,
               fun = median) +
  stat_summary(fun = median, geom = "path",
               mapping = aes(group = -1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-09-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: thanks and what is the reason behind ```group = -1```?

Comment: It can be any number, but is kind of ggplots' convention to represent 'no group' as -1. You can see this if you use `layer_data()` on an groupless layer.